# define_method inside instance_eval

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

When I define a method inside instance_eval block for class it creates a class method which is fine.

Eg)

```
class A
end

A.instance_eval do
  def method; end
end

A.method #works
```

But when I use define_method inside instance_eval it creates instance method instead of class method
Eg)

```
A.instance_eval do
  define_method(:method1) {}
end
A.method1 # NoMethodError: undefined method `method1'
A.new.method1 # Works fine
```

I am unable to understand above phenomena.  Please can somebody help me out.

Comment: If you want to make your head hurt, look up the concept of the "default definee" (that is "the thing where `def` ends up putting methods") and which of the `*_eval` methods changes `self`, which changes the default definee, which changes both, and which of the `define_*_method` methods honor the default definee and which don't. It's quite a mess.

Comment: http://yugui.jp/articles/846

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This quirky behavior makes a little more sense if you look at `instance_eval` in the context of *instances* (which is its main purpose).

```
class A
end

a = A.new
a.instance_eval do
  def foo
  end
end
```

Where is `foo` defined? The only sensible place I can think of is `a`'s singleton class, and indeed that is true

```
a.method(:foo).owner == a.singleton_class
# true
```

So this demonstrates the rule

> `def` inside `instance_eval` defines a method in `self`'s singleton class.

which is completely consistent with what you saw.

```
A.instance_eval do
  # defines method in A's singleton class!
  def method; end
end
```

So why does `define_method` behave differently? Because unlike `def` it's a *method*! So this

```
A.instance_eval do
  define_method(:foo) {}
end
```

is really just

```
A.define_method(:foo) {}
```

which is the metaprogramming way of creating normal instance methods. This inconsistency may seem annoying, but again look at the case for normal instances and you'll see why `def` and `define_method` *can't* be consistent. This

```
a.instance_eval do
  define_method(:foo) {}
end
```

is really just

```
a.define_method(:foo) {}
```

which is nonsense

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `define_method' for #<A:0x00008>
```

Answer (score 1):

Memorize this:

|  | changes `self` to | changes `current class` to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| class_eval | receiver | receiver |
| instance_eval | receiver | receiver's singleton class |

Methods defined in ruby with `def` keyword (without an explicit receiver) are always defined in the "current class" (that's what Paolo Perrotta calls it in *Metaprogramming Ruby*; others call it "[default definee](http://yugui.jp/articles/846)")

The "current class" is something we usually don't think about because it's intuitive; inside a class definition, the current class is the class itself, so methods defined with `def foo` inside a class definition become instance methods of that class.

But when you call instance_eval with the `A` class being the receiver, as per the table above, you are changing the 'current class' to the receiver's **singleton** class; since you are defining a method with `def`, it will be defined in the 'current class', which results in a 'class method' (a method defined in A's singleton class or eigenclass):

```rb
class A
end

A.instance_eval do
  # the current class here is not A, but A's singleton class; 
  def method; end
end
```

However, when you define the method with `define_method`, as per the table above, you are actually invoking `define_method` on an implicit receiver `self`; if you look at the table, `self` will be the receiver `A`, so it's the same as calling `A.define_method` or even:

```rb
class A

  define_method(:method1) {}

end
```

So that's why, in this case, you get an instance method, because you called define_method on the class A, and not in A's singleton class (or also called eigenclass).

Answer (score 0):

For:

```
class A; end

A.instance_eval do
  puts "self=#{self}"
  def m; puts "hi"; end
  define_method(:n) {puts "ho" }
end
  #=> "self=A"
```

we find that:

```
A.methods(false)          #=> [:m] 
A.instance_methods(false) #=> [:n] 
A.m                       # hi
A.n                       # NoMethodError:...
A.new.m                   # NoMethodError:...
A.new.n                   # ho
```

`A.instance_eval` opens class `A` and the method `m` is defined on `A`. Next, the method [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) is then invoked, which creates the instance method `:n` on it's receiver, `A`.

Suppose we were to use [Module#class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) rather than [BasicObject#instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval):

```
A.class_eval do
  puts "self=#{self}"
  def m; puts "hi"; end
  define_method(:n) {puts "ho" }
end
  #=> "self=A"
```

we find that:

```
A.methods(false)          #=> [] 
A.instance_methods(false) #=> [:m, :n] 
A.m                       # NoMethodError:...
A.n                       # NoMethodError:...
A.new.m                   # hi
A.new.n                   # ho
```

so you see that this behaviour is the same as:

```
class A
  puts "self=#{self}"
  def m; puts "hi"; end
  define_method(:n) {puts "ho" }
end
```

and here instance methods can be defined with either `def` or `define_method`.